# Checkbox should be filled automatically when comparing two objects

Tags: checkbox

we have the object Preinscripción containing records about which Postgraduate course someone applied for and paid. It contains the Name of the Applicant, the Postgraduate Course, the Identification Number, Status of the Preinscripción and a checkbox indicating whether a record with the same values Name of Applicant, Postgraduate Course and Identification Number exists or not in another object, the object Admission.

For example, let's say I have a record with data Name Pepe Flores, Postgraduate Course Cardiovascular Medicine, ID Number 1234567 in the object Preinscripción, if these values are also contained in the same fields in the object Admission, the checkbox should automatically be checked or populated.

There is no relationship between both objects, Preinscripción and Admission, but they have three fields in common.

Is it possible to make that work? is coding needed?.

Comment: There is no relationship between Preinscripción and Admission, but both have three fields in common.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apex trigger on any of the object. When new record creates trigger will check the necessary fields and enable the checkbox.